# Why does a new line in the editor not appear after submitting?

Tags: support, markdown, editor

This may sound a bit stupid question, but why does the "Enter" key not make this statement to go on a new line?
Please refer the snapshot below...

[image]

Comment: Try pressing two enters.

Comment: That is intentional. Add 2 spaces at the end of the line

Comment: @juergend Historically, I think it comes from the fact that you need to use 2 newlines to make a paragraph in a Plain Text file (that is visible with the naked eye). Also, before the advent of word wrapping single lines might have been used for that purpose as well. So I guess it spilled over in various markups as the way to make a paragraph.

Comment: @baplha has a nice explanation [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/45635/167646)

Comment: Please do not start a question with "Hi".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). Quoting from the [editing help page](http://www.stackoverflow.com/editing-help),

> Linebreaks
>    -
>    End a line with two spaces to add a linebreak.

Alternatively, use `<br>` or `<br/>` to add a linebreak. And [this is why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45617/why-should-users-have-to-press-return-twice-to-insert-new-lines/45635#45635)!

Answer (score 0):

You can use double enters:

newLine.

[image]